# How does implicit sorting in SELECT *,MIN(x) work in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Today I had an apparently very common problem of selecting the row with the minimum value from each group of a dataset split by a `group by`. I found a solution that is unique to SQLite (it works incorrectly in MySQL and throws an error in PostgreSQL) and doesn't use any joins. It looks like this:

```
SELECT *, min(x) FROM table GROUP BY y
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/1bceb/1) is a fiddle with an example.

However, I don't understand *why* this works - just by including an aggregate function each group was somehow implicitly sorted and returned the row to which the result of the aggregate function corresponds. Default SQL behavior is to select an arbitrary row. I dug through [relevant SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#resultset) and found no explanation of this. This is what I'd like an explanation for.

---

Edit: both answers so far guess that this is a coincidence. It is not. In the actual table I have ~90 records split into ~30 groups with this method and it works as expected on every one. [See for yourself](http://pastebin.com/g9FgaYuH).

Comment: [SQLite Release 3.7.11 On 2012-03-20](https://sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_11.html): *Queries of the form: "SELECT max(x), y FROM table" returns the value of y on the same row that contains the maximum x value.*

Comment: Reference to relevant [source commits](http://www.sqlite.org/src/timeline?r=output-minmax-row).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be compatible with MySQL, SQLite allows to use columns that are neither aggregated nor grouped by.

MySQL does not *guarantee* that the values come from any specific row, and neither did SQLite before version 3.7.11. However, due to how grouping is implemented in SQLite, the values in such columns happened to come from the row that matches the min()/max() in certain cases.

Some [paying](http://www.sqlite.org/prosupport.html) customer found this useful and wanted a guarantee for this, so SQLite [enforced it in all cases](http://www.sqlite.org/src/info/fa13edd39c3b8ec7) and [documented it in the changelog of version 3.7.11](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_11.html), which makes it a supported feature (i.e., it's tested, and will never be removed).

While it is safe to use, this behaviour is a <strike>violation</strike> extension of the SQL standard that was never properly designed, and never meant to be a selling feature, so it is not mentioned in the actual documentation.

Comment: . . Do you know if that behavior applies to multiple "y" columns?

Comment: I see a gurantee for MAX, not for MIN.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It applies to all columns.

Comment: Again, this is not what the documentation guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

It probably works by accident.  SQLite will return an arbitrary row for each group.  The row does not necessarily have to have the minimum `x` value for the group.

Learn to express the query correctly:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE t.x = (SELECT MIN(t2.x) FROM table t2 WHERE t2.y = t.y)
```

Comment: This query will not work as expected if there are more than one row with the minimum value. If this is a possibility for a certain scenario, some way has to be decided to choose between the various alternatives (find the min of a second column, for instance; or the minimum of a primary key, or...).

Comment: SQLite seems to be quite stubborn on always returning the 'correct' rows in the fiddle example, no matter how many combinations I make... So, it really doesn't look like a coincidence. If you check this:  SELECT *, max(record_date), min(record_date)
  FROM mt
  GROUP BY id ;  ... you will find that the chosen rows are the ones where the min(record_date) is actually found. If you change the order of max() and min(), you get the rows where the maximum appears. So, it doesn't really look like a coincidence.

Comment: @joanolo . . . My guess is that `id` is sequentially incremented in the data and SQLite uses a stable sort for the `group by`.  These are not conditions that I would ever want to depend on for real queries.

Answer (score 0):

The record you see was arbitrary chosen.
You cannot count on the behaviour which seems fix to you.
It can be changed due to changes in the table structure (e.g. added/removed indexes), between versions etc.

---

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html

> If the SELECT statement is an aggregate query with a GROUP BY clause
>   ...
>   Each expression in the result-set is then evaluated once for each
>   group of rows. If the expression is an aggregate expression, it is
>   evaluated across all rows in the group. Otherwise, it is evaluated
>   against a single arbitrarily chosen row from within the group. If
>   there is more than one non-aggregate expression in the result-set,
>   then all such expressions are evaluated for the same row.

---

This reminds me of a famous pitfall related to Oracle's GROUP BY.
Everybody **just knew** that if you use GROUP BY you can skip the ORDER BY because the result set is already ordered.
The reason the result set was ordered at that time is that Oracle used a sort based algorithm for the implementation of the group by.
In version 10gR2 Oracle added an additional GROUP BY algorithm based on **HASH**.
You can guess the rest of the story.